# Magnific Popup, can't fire function on ajax content after callback

Tags: jquery, magnific-popup

I'm trying to fire a slideshow after an ajax call of this lightbox, but with no luck. It seems that parseAjax callback was fired before html injection, is it true?

here is my code:

```
     $('.image-link').magnificPopup({
    type:'ajax',
    callbacks: {

        parseAjax: function(jqXHR) {

            var newSlider = $('body')
                .find('.ajaxSlider')
                .royalSlider({
                   // options
                }).data('royalSlider');

        },
        close: function() {

            newSlider.destroy();

        }

    }

 });

<div class="ajaxSlider"></div> // fyo this is ajax content
```

Any idea? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`parseAjax` callback fires before the content is added to DOM. Use `updateStatus` callback, or add a short timeout.

```
updateStatus: function(data) {
    if(data.status === 'ready') {
        //
    }
}
```

Also, you may just put your JS logic inside the ajax file.